# Logging: How to filter INFO messages from request library?

Tags: python

How can I filter messages from the requests library like this:

```
requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool: INFO     [9706] Starting new HTTPS connection (1): foohost
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
logging.getLogger('requests').setLevel(logging.WARN)
```